# MarkLogic geojson.geospatialQuery returns all records

Tags: geospatial, geojson, marklogic

I have a MarkLogic Collection with GeoJson elements

```
instance{
    ...    
    geoJson:{
      "type": "Feature", 
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point", 
      "coordinates": 
                       [
                        -35.348735749, 
                        149.157085419
                      ]

    }
  ...
}
```

I want to find those that are with in a radius of another point/ I have followed the documentation on GeoSpatial Searching and utilised the geoJSON library

```
const geojson = require('/MarkLogic/geospatial/geojson')
```

and utilised the geospatialQuery and cts.circle but even though this should exclude the above record it is included in the result set. They are 821km (510m) apart and the radius is set to 10m. In fact the following doesn't seem to reduce the result set at all.

```
 var uris =  cts.uris("/Coll*",["limit=10"],                        
 geojson.geospatialQuery(
      cts.circle(10,cts.point(-28.7885974,153.16786679999996))
    ,null,1.0)
           ).toArray()
```

> **I have found the issue... This geospatial query works perfectly in cts.search but not with cts.uris. This is because for some reason the $query parameter in cts.uris is unfiltered ?!? This is documented by MarkLogic in [cts.uri - $query](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.uris)... i do wonder why? But more to the point how do I change it to filtered?**

the following **works** and does return the documents that are within the radius of that point

```
 var uris =  cts.search(                        
 geojson.geospatialQuery(
      cts.circle(10,cts.point(-28.7885974,153.16786679999996))
    )
```

Comment: What exact version of MarkLogic are you using?

Comment: It was suggested that the coordinates in the document was a string not a float and in fact this was true. But after changing all to float I still get all records not some and not the ones i want.

Comment: I have discovered the Query works if wrapped in a cts.search() but not if used as part of a query in a function like cts.uris("/coll*",null,QUERY)

Comment: Check if you have a license that covers geospatial.

Comment: geospatial works for cts.search not cts.uris query so I dont think the licence is the issue

Comment: Cts.uris always runs unfiltered. Cts.search by default filtered. Try cts.search with unfiltered option..

Comment: Why would you have a query option that doesn't reduce? How do you run cts.uris in filtered mode?

Comment: cts.uris is a lexicon lookup, e.g. it uses indexes only. You need the documents themselves to do filtering, e.g. a search. Doing filtering on any lookup would be very expensive, but you could do it with an XPath predicate or a FLWOR if you insist.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. Still confused why the cts.uris has a query argument that works for word searches but not geospatial... But I have moved on

Answer (score 1):

When you are getting lots of false positive results that require filtering, then the first thing to do is verify that the necessary backing indexes have been created and are available.

If you serialize the query and inspect the generated query criteria:

```
cts.pathGeospatialQuery(
  ["geometry[type='Point']/array-node('coordinates')", 
   "geometry[type='MultiPoint']/array-node('coordinates')/array-node('coordinates')"], 
  cts.circle("@10 -28.788597,153.16787"), 
  ["coordinate-system=wgs84","type=long-lat-point"], 
  1)
```

So, when executing `geojson.geospatialQuery` with `cts.circle` query, the following indexes should be created and available.

Geospatial Path Index (Point, JSON)

- Path expression: `geometry[type = 'Point']/array-node('coordinates')`
- Coordinate system: `wgs84`
- Point format: `long-lat-point`

Geospatial Path Index (MultiPoint, JSON)

- Path expression: `geometry[type = 'MultiPoint']/array-node('coordinates')/array-node('coordinates')`
- Coordinate system: `wgs84`
- Point format: `long-lat-point`

You can use [`cts.plan()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.plan) to get an understanding of what indexes are being used and how many fragments are selected to filter.

```
cts.plan( 
  geojson.geospatialQuery(
    cts.circle(10,cts.point(-28.7885974,153.16786679999996))
) )
```

Answer (score 0):

please review your data.

```
"coordinates": [
                   [
                    "-35.348735749", 
                    "149.157085419"
                  ]
                ]
```

That shows an array within an array. for GeoJson points, this does not make sense - and does not match the xPath expression on the configureation `//geometry[type = "Point"]/array-node("coordinates")`

Comment: Ok Yep they may be right originally they were MultiPoints so an array of points. Will change and check. Soesn't answer why i get all records. I should get none.
ACTUALLY after checking the data is just one array of two points as expected for a GeoJSON the example was wrong. (I will update)